# Commas in Powershell hash table key

Tags: powershell

Take this .txt file:

```
11111-2222, My, file, is, here.xml
22222-1111, My, filename.xml
22222-2323, My filename 2.xml
22222-2323, Myfilename3.xml
```

This text file represents a map linking ID's with names of files on a filesystem directory (each row is an entry, seperated by the first comma following the ID number). I have a powershell script that at a high-level will import this .txt file as CSV and put it in a map to where I can match a filename with it's corresponding ID number, which I need to append to a PUT request to an endpoint.

My script is working great for lines 3 and 4 above in the .txt... except for the filenames that have commas. Since we are delimiting with commas, Powershell is cutting off those field names short, causing for incorrect field values.

Code snippet:

```
$mapFile = "location\of\mytextfilehere.txt"
$contentObjects = "location\of\filesIwantToPost"
$map = @{}
Import-Csv $mapFile -Header ID,Filename | ForEach-Object { $map[$_.Filename] = $_.ID }

foreach ($file in $contentObjects) {
        $content = Get-Content $object.PSPath
        $putURI = "http://myendpoint:3000/" + $map[$file.Name]
            $request = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $putURI -Method PUT -Body $content
}
```

The above breaks when trying to PUT the file `"My, file, is, here.xml"` and `"My, filename.xml"`. The map building saves only "My, " as the key value, since we are comma delimited.
Is there a way to help me deal with these commas and save these fields completely and correctly? Perhaps by delimiting my .txt with pipes instead of commas? Or is there a different alternate approach?

Comment: Your input isn't CSV. A CSV file would have a delimiter around any values with special characters.

Comment: @Eris it's a normal .txt file that I convert to CSV later.....

Comment: @Eris is correct.  You are using `Import-Csv` on a file that is not CSV.

Comment: Ah forgot to mention I'm building this through another process so the .txt file needs to look like that. I'm trying to build it with quotes around each entry to see if that'll help.

Answer (score 0):

Your file is not CSV. Wrap names with quotes or parse it manually like below:

```
#test data
new-item sample.txt -ItemType File -Value "11111-2222, My, file, is, here.xml
22222-1111, My, filename.xml
22222-2323, My filename 2.xml
22222-2323, Myfilename3.xml"

#parse
cat sample.txt | %{
    $ID, $File = $_ -split ',',2;
    [PSCustomObject]@{ ID=$ID; File=$File.Trim() }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @wOxxOm, fixed.